# We know that $4x^2y\sqrt{1-x^2} - 4xy\cos\alpha + y^2\sqrt{4-2y^2} = 0$, To find $4x^2 - 4xy\cos\alpha + y^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inverse-function

I'm supposed to find the value of the expression $$4x^2 - 4xy\cos\alpha + y^2$$

Given, $$\cos^{-1}(x) - \cos^{-1}(\frac{y}{2}) = \alpha$$

Using some trigonometric manipulation I've arrived at the equation $$4x^2(y\sqrt{1-x^2}) - 4xy\cos\alpha + y^2(\sqrt{4-2y^2}) = 0$$ which looks oddly similar to the the expression which I need to find. Is there any method to go from the equation to that expression?

Adding to this, is there any method to go from $Ax^{n}\alpha + By^{m}\beta + Cxy\gamma + O(D,F,..,\delta,\varepsilon,...) = 0$ to $Ax^n + By^n + Cxy + O(D,F,..) = k$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you got your equation, but here's a way to solve the problem using trigonometric manipulation. Let

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
& a = \cos^{-1}(x) \;\;\to\;\; x = \cos(a), \; \sin(a) = \pm\sqrt{1-x^2} \\
& b = \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{2}\right) \;\;\to\;\; \frac{y}{2} = \cos(b), \; \sin(b) = \pm\sqrt{1-\frac{y^2}{4}}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

Next, from the list of [angle sum and difference identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities), using

$$\cos(a-b) = \cos(a)\cos(b) + \sin(a)\sin(b)$$

we get from the given equation by taking $\cos()$ of both sides that

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\cos(\alpha) & = x\left(\frac{y}{2}\right) \pm\sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{1-\frac{y^2}{4}} \\
2\cos(\alpha) - xy & = \pm\sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{4-y^2} \\
(2\cos(\alpha) - xy)^2 & = (1 - x^2)(4 - y^2) \\
4\cos^2(\alpha) - 4xy\cos(\alpha) + x^2y^2 & = 4 - y^2 - 4x^2 + x^2y^2 \\
4x^2 - 4xy\cos(\alpha) + y^2 & = 4 - 4\cos^2(\alpha) \\
4x^2 - 4xy\cos(\alpha) + y^2 & = 4\sin^2(\alpha)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

Comment: I guess I have to apologize that I have made some trivial mistakes while trying to solve the problem. Thank you for your answer!